# Cup/cap product: sheaf cohomology vs singular cohomology

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Is anyone aware of a good resource which deals with how the cup/cap products of sheaf cohomology classes are a generalization of those in singular cohomology? I would say that I already understand the basics of both constructions.

Specifically, I am asking how the cup product from singular cohomology is actually a special case of cup-product-as-Yoneda-product from sheaf cohomology.

Comment: Are you asking why they agree for constant sheaves?

Comment: Sheaf cohomology for constant sheaves is not that much different from the simplicial cohomology (the only essential difference is taking a limit) and the cup-product works the same way. I suggest you first work out this case by yourself. Then read Chapter 2.7 of Bredon's "Sheaf Theory" for the case of general sheaves.

Comment: @MikeMiller Yes.

Comment: @studiosus Do you mean "singular cohomology" when you say "simplicial cohomology"? The cup product I'm familiar with on sheaves is in terms of $\operatorname{Ext}^j(\underline{k}, \underline{k})$, and I was trying to bring that down to earth a bit. I know how to show that singular equals sheaf cohomology in nice cases.

Comment: I mean simplicial.